Issues importing module from py file
enter image description here
I am trying to import a module from a .py file. I'm supposed to be testing my crud for an assignment but when I import the module I get an error. Can anyone help?
I have the .py file and the .ipynb file in the same directory, but for some reason the import name isn't being recognized.
My .py file code is also pictured. enter image description here

Looks like you might have to capitalize the S in 'import Animalshelter'.  Also check for circular imports.


Check your directories. I've read that you have checked the directories but no harm in doing another pass.
import os
print(os.getcwd())


Check for syntax errors on the animal_shelter.py, unrelated but _init_() is not a constructor but __init__() is.

Restart the notebook kernel, or just close and reopen it altogether.


